# Are there downsides to just always using .andWhere instead of .where in TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

A drawback of TypeORM's query builder is that when you use multiple .where conditions, then only the last one is actually used. In practice, it seems like I could just always use .andWhere, and never .where, as if you pass only 1 or more .andWhere conditions (without a .where) this still translates to a correct query (let's forget about more complicated where clauses and .orWhere for now).

So my question, can I safely take this as a guideline in future work, or does .where actually have any value on top of .andWhere that I'm missing?

A very basic query like
`repository.createQueryBuilder('something') .select('something.something') .andWhere('something.something = :something', { something: something, })`
simply translates to `SELECT something FROM something WHERE something = 'something'`

The same when you use 2 .andWhere clauses.

Comment: Using `.where` will ensure that you clear your conditions if there were any. Also always using `.andWhere` adds overhead, but that is way too small to notice.

Comment: @Justinas which overhead?

Comment: @Bergi Checking if there is any already existing conditions and adding to them.

Comment: @Justinas to me it sounds like `where` has the overhead of checking for and removing existing conditions, whereas `andWhere` would simply always add… But this is an implementation detail and indeed any difference will be insignificant.